# Extend PDO Execute() to Count Queries on Page

Tags: php, pdo

Ok, similar questions has been asked and answered before. However, I want to count prepared queries as well. I thought I could just use the prepare() function to increment the query count but that provided me some questionable results. Right now, it's telling me 10 queries are being executed... Generally I only use prepared statements unless the data is static or cannot be modified in anyway.

I found this code from another question that was identical to this. Except that the code only was counting queries that were executed using the query() and exec() functions. I tried to modify it but as I said before it isn't counting any prepared queries but the queries are still executed and return results...

```
class PDOEx extends PDO
{
    private $queryCount = 0;

    public function query($query)
    {
        ++$this->queryCount;

        return parent::query($query);
    }

    public function exec($statement)
    {
        ++$this->queryCount;

        return parent::exec($statement);
    }

    public function execute($args = null)
    {
        ++$this->queryCount;

        if (!is_array($args)) {
            $args = func_get_args();
        }

        return parent::execute($args);
    }

    public function GetCount()
    {
        return $this->queryCount;
    }
}
```

I just want to say thanks in advance. Please, if you can point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason prepared queries aren't being counted is because it returns a PDOStatement, which is different than PDO. You could just ask the database how many queries were run on a given session, so as long as you don't keep create new `\PDO` objects then the result will be correct. Keep in mind even that query is counted as a query, so if you want to exclude it subtract 1 from the value.

> Code

```
$db = new \PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=sandbox', 'localuser', 'password');
$db->query('SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = 5');
$db->query('UPDATE user SET name = 'Demo' WHERE id = 5');
$db->query('DELETE FROM user WHERE id = 5');
echo $db->query('SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE "Questions"')->fetchColumn(1);
```

> Output

```
4
```

Comment: I tried extending PDOStatement (which was offered as a suggestion) and have the execute for the prepared queries in there. I could not get it working. how can I make the queryCount parameter in this class the same as the class posted above?
`class db_statement extends PDOStatement 
{
 protected $pdo;
 protected function __construct($pdo)
 {
  $this->pdo = $pdo;
 }
 
 public function execute($args = null)
 {
  // Increment the counter.
        ++$this->queryCount;
  
  if (!is_array($args)) {
   $args = func_get_args();
  }

  return parent::execute($args);
 }
}`
Or will this not work at all?

Comment: You will have to do a lot of class overriding, my answer above requires no class overriding at all. Are you not able to use the code provided above?

Comment: Yes, thank you. I retracted all my class overrides and went back to this. It seems much cleaner and easier to do it this way... THANK YOU AGAIN!